# multiple references same base64 img

Tags: html, css, image, base64

Is it possible to reuse some image that is inserted in the code as base64?
In my specific case, I have a list of `div`'s, each of which has as the first element a `img` set by base 64. There are three or four images, but so far what I have done is loading the image like 10 or 20 times (what seems unlogical)

I was trying to do something like this:

```
.image1 {
    src="data:img/png;base64,iVB(base64 here)..."
}

.image2 {
    src="data:img/png;base64,aQp(base64 here)..."
}
.image3 {
    src="data:img/png;base64,aPl8(base64 here)..."
}
```

and then add to each div a `<img class='image1'>` etc.

It requires that the image be base64, not some .png or .jpeg.

If there is another elegant way to do that I'd gladly try also.

Comment: Does the requirement that this be BASE64 mean it's an email? That would change the possibilities a bit. Otherwise, give all the divs the same background-image through CSS.

Comment: it's not an e-mail. I'll try using the div + background-image approach. Thanks!

Comment: Is it all same image or different?